# Is there a way to tell if a Receiver is a Reliable Receiver?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I can't seem to find anywhere that would let a user know if the receiver they
are using is reliable or not. Even better would be a list of known reliable
receivers. Are any of these things possible? Or do you just have to research
your receiver beforehand?